# not able to execute command window.document.execCommand("paste") in brackets

Tags: jquery, dom, npm, brackets-shell

I wrote a plugin  in brackets in which I want to copy text from the text box and paste in the current opened document .

```
window.document.execCommand("copy");
```

if I use keyboard command+v its working, I am able to paste the text which is copied by the above dom command.

But the same result I'm not able to get by `window.document.execCommand("paste")`, even though I tried this `CommandManager.execute(Commands.EDIT_PASTE)` too.

could you help me please.

Regards
Ashish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those commands won't work because Brackets runs in a Chromium webview, and Chromium doesn't permit normal content to access the clipboard programmatically - as a security measure.  In Brackets the security rationale isn't really relevant, but someone would need to patch brackets-shell to disable the restriction, and that work hasn't happened yet.

But there's a workaround: Brackets extensions [have access to NodeJS](https://github.com/adobe/brackets/wiki/Brackets-Node-Process%3a-Overview-for-Developers), so you can use a Node package like [copy-paste](https://www.npmjs.org/package/copy-paste) to access the clipboard. Check out the source of the extensions [Right Click Extended](https://github.com/jbardnz/RightClickExtended) or [File Info to Clipboard](https://github.com/VinceMalone/Brackets-FileInfoToClipboard) for examples.