# paste data from clipboard using document.execCommand("paste"); within firefox extension

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, clipboard, clipboarddata

I am trying to paste clipboard data into a variable that gets fed into and fired via XMLhttprequest POST message.

I have created a firefox user.js with this code to increase access to clipboard based on this [recommendation](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Granting_JavaScript_access_to_the_clipboard).

```
user_pref("capability.policy.policynames", "allowclipboard");
user_pref("capability.policy.allowclipboard.sites", "mydomain");
user_pref("capability.policy.allowclipboard.Clipboard.cutcopy", "allAccess");
user_pref("capability.policy.allowclipboard.Clipboard.paste", "allAccess");
```

Do I need to change "mydomain" in line two? I do not want any sites to have access. Just my internal firefox extension.

I have read several guides [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23910353/not-able-to-execute-command-window-document-execcommandpaste-in-brackets) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22702446/how-to-get-clipboard-data-in-chrome-extension/22702538#22702538) as well as [mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.execCommand#Commands).

Here is the code I have so far. The clipboard contents should get sent POST method via `XMLHttpRequest`. `XMLHttpRequest` works, as I have been using it for other variables.

```
 var pastetext = document.execCommand('paste');
 var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
 req.open('POST', pastetext, true);
 req.onreadystatechange = function(aEvt) {
     if (req.readyState == 4) {
         if (req.status == 200)
             dump(req.responseText);
         else
             dump("Error loading page\n");
     }
 };
 req.send(null);
```

I am grateful for any help.
Thank you

Comment: I do not fully understand user.js, although from what I understand once I create it I can change my security settings regarding manipulating data from clipboard. I believe you are correct in that I do not actually need it for my requiprements. Thank you for your explanation, solution works beautifully!

Comment: My pleasure. Creative way to reply as you don't have enough rep to reply to the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is not the `execCommand` but you need to read the data from the clipboard. Your addon is in privelaged scope so you don't need to worry about those preferences. (user.js is firefox-addon right?)

See here:

- [MDN :: Using the Clipboard](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_the_Clipboard#Pasting_Clipboard_Contents)
- [MDN :: nsIClipboard](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XPCOM/Reference/Interface/nsIClipboard)

This way you can read the contents into the var `pastedContents`.

Here is your example with the above worked in:

```
var trans = Cc["@mozilla.org/widget/transferable;1"].createInstance(Ci.nsITransferable);
trans.addDataFlavor("text/unicode");
Services.clipboard.getData(trans, Services.clipboard.kGlobalClipboard);
var pastetextNsiSupports = {};
var pastetextNsiSupportsLength = {};
trans.getTransferData("text/unicode", pastetextNsiSupports, pastetextNsiSupportsLength);

var pastetext = pastetextNsiSupports.value.QueryInterface(Ci.nsISupportsString).data;
 var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
 req.open('POST', pastetext, true);
 req.onreadystatechange = function(aEvt) {
     if (req.readyState == 4) {
         if (req.status == 200)
             dump(req.responseText);
         else
             dump("Error loading page\n");
     }
 };
 req.send(null);
```