# Add data from clipboard to out-of-page inputs via firefox addon

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I develop an addon for Firefox and have the next question: is there a way to paste data from clipboard to borwser elements like a search or url field using Firefox addon api? And what is the best way to solve such kind of problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes get the data on the clipboard with: [paste data from clipboard using document.execCommand("paste"); within firefox extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26545871/paste-data-from-clipboard-using-document-execcommandpaste-within-firefox-ex/26554409#26554409)

Then do `Services.wm.getMostRecentWindow('navigator:browser').gURLBar.value = varHoldingPasteData;`